# Is it correct to use if statement within try statement?

Tags: python

I am wondering if it is correct to use `if` statement within the `try` clause, because I was told to separate the two but the code ended up printing both messages, for instance:

```
def select_choice():

    print(MATH_OPERATIONS)

    while True:
        try:
            user_inp = int(input("Select an operator | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |: "))

            if user_inp > 5:
                print("\nOption selected must be from 1 to 5 only!\n")
            else:
                return user_inp
                 
        except ValueError:
            print("\nINVALID INPUT - Field must not be blank or contained non-numerical values.\n")
```

I tried to move the code block of `if-else` after the `except` statement, that was where the issue occur.

Comment: The code you've shown is just fine.

Comment: The `Try` section should ideally only have code which might result in exceptions. Look up the construct for a `Try-Except-Else`. You can put your logic and code you want to run in the case the `Try` does not have an exception.

Comment: Technically, it would be more stylistically correct to move the infallible part out of the `try` block (into an `else` block as purple said), but if you're just starting out then don't worry about such pedantry and just try to write code that *works*, which you've absolutely done here.

Comment: btw, check out this awesome syntax sugar: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Comment: @roganjosh this strikes me as a comment whereby you want to appear clever but actually something else happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion was probably to write something like

```
while True:
    response = input("...")

    try:
        user_inp = int(response)
    except ValueError:
        print("\nINVALID INPUT - Field must not be blank or contained non-numerical values.\n")
        continue

    if 1 <= user_inp <= 5:
        return user_inp
    
    print("\nOption selected must be from 1 to 5 only!\n")
```

You get the response, first: it can't raise a value error caused by user input (only by you passing an incorrect argument to `input` in the first place). Once you have the response, you attempt to create an `int` value from it. That *can* raise a `ValueError`, which you will handle by continue the loop immediately to ask for another response.

Once `int` succeeds, the `try` statement completes, with the guarantee that `user_inp` is an `int`, so you can proceed with the range check *outside* the `try` statement.

As before, the only way out of the loop is to return after a successful range check.

Comment: thank you... this is what I was looking for, it takes in both factors. And sorry, can't upvote, it says I need at least 15 reputations, but I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: @RoyalFrog Eh, nobody gets the rep for this answer anyway; I marked it as a community wiki because it's mostly a distillation of everyone's comments.